# How two different applications should get served using apache2 virtualhost configuration

Tags: php, django, magento, apache2, web-deployment

Just for assumption here

`testsite.com` which is my php application and

`testsite.com/project` is python application

I have following settings in my apache site config file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/site.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@testsite.com

                DocumentRoot /var/www/html

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@testsite.com

                DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test-project

                <Directory /var/www/html/test-project/test-project>
                    <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                    </Files>
                </Directory>
                WSGIDaemonProcess test python-path=/var/www/html/test-project/test-project python-home=/var/www/html/test-project
                WSGIProcessGroup test
                WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/test-project/test-project/wsgi.py

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Looking at above config, I just want any url with `testsite.com/` will get served from first virtualhost which is my php application and its working and whenever only this specific `testsite.com/project` url hits then it should get served from second virtualhost which is my python application.

So inorder to get this url `testsite.com/project` served from second virtualhost it has to get bypass from first virtualhost.
Please suggest how do I do that ? What should I do in first virtualhost so that it wil get bypassed to second.

**NOTE: This is not related with url rewriting so please do not suggest anything rewriting rule or anything regarding that.**

Comment: Most probably you are thinking about something like [reverse-proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html) most probably asking this question at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) would be a better option.

Comment: Sure, I have done that. Thanks for informing ! Also if you know the exact solution in my case scenario, then can you please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't ;) just doing other things. I'm pretty sure that reverse proxy is what you're looking for and you can try some approaches if it fits your needs. Otherwise, let's hope that guys from ServerFault's will give you some better clues ;)